# Enjoy Hawaiian hotspring in China

Tags: technological-development

As a pact between China and USA to improve bilateral relationship between the 2 nations, USA agrees to provide constant flows of molten lava fresh from Hawaii to the Chinese. On the other hand China will loan out 100 millions USD as part of the treatise. You reader are hired to be our lead engineer and scientist, you must irrigate the lava from Hawaii to Beijing, the capital of China. Set in modern times use anything available in that period no worry about logistic and manpower issues and I doubt any nation dare disrupt this important deal. How can I implement a transpacific irrigation system of molten lava from Mauna Loa and Kilauea, active volcanoes in Hawaii across the North Pacific ocean go round Japan and South Korea to its destination Beijing within a time frame of a century?

Comment: I see no possible way a Renaissance-era society could achieve this. i doubt we could do it with modern technology. 1) [Magma is extremely hot](http://education.nationalgeographic.com/encyclopedia/magma/) and, 2) there's a lot of an excellent cooling material between Hawaii and China.

Comment: @Frostfyre I've corrected to modern times, have a go.

Comment: They have volcanoes in China too and Japan also has plenty, it would be easier to transport the lava https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_volcanoes_in_China

Comment: What would you do with molten lava?  If you want geothermal power, far easier to do so at the source, where you have a nice heat sink handy, and ship the electrons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a distance of 5.4K miles between Hawaii and Beijing.  The crust is between 20-30 miles thick.  So figuring out how to dig a deep hole through the crust.  The Chinese have drilled wells over 800 ft. deep back in the [first century B.C](http://www.historylines.net/history/chinese/oil_well.html).

The first transatlantic cable was laid in 1858 between [Scotland and Newfoundland](http://www.history.com/this-day-in-history/first-transatlantic-telegraph-cable-completed) it was 2226 miles, 1/2 the distance you are talking and all it transported was electrons.

Currently the longest pipeline in the world for transporting natural gas/oil is the length we are talking 5.4K miles.  It also happens to be in China.  It connects [Xinjiang to Shanghai](http://petroglobalnews.com/2013/10/top-ten-longest-oil-pipelines/).  This was built on land and transports gas and liquid that does not require high temperatures.

So, the most efficient would be to drill in China for it.  China has a [list of volcanoes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_volcanoes_in_China) and other [hot springs](http://www.travelchinaguide.com/essential/hot-spring-tips.htm) that it could tap in country, several locations 1,000 Km or less from Beijing, which would be much easier to move.

5.4K miles of Ocean would be an engineering challenge just to build a pipeline to carry oil.  It constantly moves and is terribly corrosive.  Adding in the need for extreme thermal protection, so the pipe doesn't turn into a rock filled tube is a whole issue by itself.  Then the need to move it that distance.  The pressure pushing that much mass that distance would like cause fatal stresses on the tubes.

We don't have anything that can stop/redirect lava right now other than cement barriers.  So we have a long way to go just to transfer lava from one side of the island to the other, unless you wait for it to cool, mine it and send it on ships...

Comment: lol just send them container ships full of gravel made from volcanic rock, *just add heat*

Comment: @James  That would be my recommendation!

Comment: I can see the packaging in my head...its funny.

Comment: @James set Oven for 1300-2000 F depending on desired viscosity...